# Non-transparent Status Bar without displaying navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I am trying to hide navigation bar and have non-transparent status bar. However, somehow I have limitation to **not to create UIView** for status bar background.

The problem is that status bar becomes transparent after I set navigation bar hidden and it overlaps on tableview scroll.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

I am wondering how can I make the status bar non-transparent, without creating UIView for its background for only single UIViewController (not for all controllers because I want it to be transparent in some).

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the status bar itself is always transparent. The alternatives from the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/status-bars/) that are relevant to you:

> - Display a custom image, like a gradient or solid color, behind the status bar.
> - Place a blurred view behind the status bar. For developer guidance, see UIBlurEffect.

You mention table view scroll. Could be that you have UITableViewController, meaning you cannot add a subview to viewController.view. You can create a custom container view controller that adds the view under the status bar, see the section *Implementing a Container View Controller* in the [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller). You then nest your nest your view controller in this container.